# PHP Radius: Set Cisco Attribute-Value Pairs (AVPairs)

Tags: php, authentication, cisco, radius

I have a CISCO and I want to authenticate users with RADIUS using PHP. CISCO has its own vendor and attributes and I have to set them in my PHP scripts. I am using [PECL RADIUS API](https://pecl.php.net/package/radius).

This is my sample code:

```
$radius = radius_auth_open();

radius_add_server($radius, $ip_address, $port, $shared_secret, 5, 3);
radius_create_request($radius, RADIUS_ACCESS_REQUEST);

// How to set CISCO attributes here?

$result = radius_send_request($radius);
```

I've tried `radius_put_attr`, `radius_put_string`, `radius_put_vendor_attr`, `radius_put_vendor_string` and other methods but none of them works.

I've tried another open source library ([Pure PHP Radius](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4326-PHP-Authenticate-users-with-a-RADIUS-server.html)) that uses Sockets and UDP to communicate with RADIUS server but I cannot set my own attributes either.

There is not enough examples out there so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check bellow code it works for me will work for you as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$radius = radius_auth_open();
radius_add_server($radius, "172.17.10.1",1812, "12345", 5, 3);
radius_create_request($radius, RADIUS_ACCESS_REQUEST);

radius_put_attr($radius, RADIUS_USER_PASSWORD, "mouse");


radius_put_vendor_attr (  $radius , 9 , 250 , "S115.12.11.10" );

radius_put_attr (  $radius , RADIUS_USER_NAME , "testusername" ) ;
radius_put_addr ($radius,RADIUS_NAS_IP_ADDRESS,"172.17.10.9");
radius_put_attr (  $radius , 87   , "0x0"  );
radius_put_vendor_attr (  $radius , 9 , 249 , "mypassword" );
radius_put_vendor_attr (  $radius , 9 , 252 , "\001" );
radius_put_vendor_string (  $radius , 9 , 250 , "S115.12.11.10" );
$result = radius_send_request($radius);

switch ($result) {
case RADIUS_ACCESS_ACCEPT:
  // An Access-Accept response to an Access-Request indicating that the RADIUS server authenticated the user successfully.
  echo 'Authentication successful';
  break;
case RADIUS_ACCESS_REJECT:
  // An Access-Reject response to an Access-Request indicating that the RADIUS server could not authenticate the user.
  echo 'Authentication failed';
  break;
case RADIUS_ACCESS_CHALLENGE:
  // An Access-Challenge response to an Access-Request indicating that the RADIUS server requires further information in another Access-Request before authenticating the user.
  echo 'Challenge required';
  break;
default:
  die('A RADIUS error has occurred: ' . radius_strerror($radius));
}
```

> Below are Cisco custom attributes description
>
> 250-> Cisco-Account-Info
>
> 252-> Cisco-Command-Code
>
> 249-> Cisco-Subscriber-Password
>
> 87-> NAS-Port-ID

http://docstore.mik.ua/univercd/cc/td/doc/product/access/acs_serv/6510ssg/6510sw11/app_d_rd.htm